# Django Model save() retains mutable reference for JSONFields()

Tags: django, django-models, django-jsonfield

```py
# Model contains only one JSON field
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field = JSONField(default=dict)

# Dictionary, assigned to model.field
field_json = {"test": 5}
model = TestModel(field = field_json)
model.save() 

# Returns true. WHY???
print(id(model.field) == id(field_json))
```

After saving a model, shouldn't the model refresh from db? Why is the model field retaining a mutable reference to the original dictionary object?

Comment: No the object is not refreshed from the database. It simply updates the record at the database side.

Answer (score 0):

> After saving a model, shouldn't the model refresh from db?

No, it **is not refreshed**. It simply makes an `CREATE` or `INSERT INTO` statement at the database. So here it will look like:

```
INSERT INTO appname_test_model (field) VALUES ('{"test": 5}');
```

That is all, the object remains the same. In fact if you for example have a `DecimalField` and you assign it an `int`, it will still remain an `int`.

If the primary key is an `AutoField` (or a `BigAutoField`), it will also set the primary key of the object the first time it saves that object:

As specified in [*Saving objects* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects):

> To save an object back to the database, call `save()`.
>
> (…)
>
> The model save process also has some subtleties; see the sections below.
>
> **Auto-incrementing primary keys**
>
> If a model has an `AutoField` — an auto-incrementing primary key — then that **auto-incremented value will be calculated and saved as an attribute** on your object the first time you call `save()`.

Comment: Thank you Willem. However, for example a model which does not have a pk, after saving has a pk assigned. Isn't this id coming from the DB? So in that case, the object is actually not the same right?

Comment: @NeilSanghrajka: yes, it will indeed select the latest assigned primary key, but that is the only thing that returns from the database.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to find Django documentation which explains this behaviour. If you can point me to some documentation, that would be awesome! Again thank you so much!!